# What is the name of this section?

Tags: civil-engineering, beam, standards

I am trying to identify the section designation so I can determine it's properties.

[image]

I have looked under "C 150 x 100 x 40" but I can't find its properties or what it's correct designation.

What is this section called? It's not just a "channel" is it?

Comment: no I didnt mean that, I just failed to find the properties of this type of beam and I looked everywhere and I cant even find its proper designation, I am only asking about what this section is called

Comment: This looks like it is probably part of a modular system - maybe pallet rack style shelving. If so, it is usually made to the specifications of a particular manufacturer, and will be a custom shape folded from sheet steel. I'm not aware of a standard shape that looks like this. If you can find the manufacturer, they probably have the information. If not, you'll have to measure it in detail and calculate the section properties yourself. We can help with that if you have trouble calculating a property.

Comment: @MohamedHassanAllam Can you be more specific about "properties"? Are you looking for stiffness characteristics, load capacity (if so, in which direction), etc.? Properties is very general and could mean any number of things.

Comment: Also, is this a figure of the C150x100x40 section or is it merely an example of this sort of shape? As GlenH7 mentions in a comment under his answer, this figure seems square (or at least the height doesn't seem to be 50% greater than the width). If this is indeed an exact figure of the C150x100, then all standard designation rules are out the window.

Comment: @TrevorArchibald I was mainly looking for weight per length

Comment: @Wasabi well supposedly yes, this was a figure of the section, but I agree with you about the possible inaccuracy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be either a C-Channel or a Box-Channel.

From the information gathered at this [manufacturer's reference](http://www.johnsonrollforming.com/display.php/display/A2/category/3), it appears that you'll need to identify a few more characteristics of the beam before you can determine its properties.

Here's a sample image and expected specifications for box channel [from that previous reference](http://www.johnsonrollforming.com/display.php/display/A2/category/3).  This would be a cold rolled section made of light gauge sheet metal.

[image: box channel]

<sub>*[click to expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9x30.jpg)*</sub>

There is also hot rolled C-channel, which has a different shape.

[image: steel c-channel]

And [some sites](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/american-standard-steel-channels-d_1321.html) will provide properties for standard sizes of that channel.

It's hard to tell from the image, but it appears to be rectangular tubing, so the 150 is likely millimeters and is the channel height.  You'll either need to provide more information or perform additional research on your own in order to determine what the 100 and 40 values refer to.

Comment: The designation is often height x width x stiffener height. However, the thickness is also necessary.

Comment: @Wasabi That's what I had thought, thanks.  The image posted appears square though, which made me wonder.

Comment: May be worth nothing that this is a cold-rolled (light-gauge) section, which is made of sheet steel.  This is as opposed to hot-rolled sections, which "normal" structural C-shapes are.

Answer (score 4):

In the Southern African context this would be defined as a

"cold formed lipped channel" section. I am not sure if it the same across the world though.

Here is one [supplier's link](http://www.macsteel.co.za/products/cold-formed-sections?b=55)